# Updating Fields using Case Qquery

Tags: sql

Supposedly, there is a tv channel 'bbc' which fall in entertainment_pack as well as extra_pack. 
I want to write a case statement such that, bbc fall in both the packages under the column Packages.

Like,

```
Select channel_name, 
       case when channel_name = 'bbc' then entertainment_pack
            when channel_name = 'bbc' then extra_pack end as Packages
From TableA
```

But the problem is bbc is updating to one package and not to both. Please suggest the best way forward.

Comment: Without sample desired output, field definitions and flavour of SQL that you are using it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I think you're trying to oversimplify the question...  what would  be returned in packages for other channels? How is this information stored?

Comment: Channel_Name Packages
BBC          Entertainment
BBC          Extra Pack
ESPN         Sports
ESPN HD      Sports Extra
ESPN         Sports Basic

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this with a join or union because you want more rows in the output than in the input:

```
Select a.channel_name, p.package_name
From TableA a left outer join
     (select 'bbc' as channel_name, 'entertainment_pack' as package union all
      select 'bbc' as channel_name, 'extra_pack' as package
     ) p
     on a.channel_name = p.channel_name;
```

This will return `NULL` for non-BBC channels.  You can add additional packages into the `p` subquery.